# Powershell script to copy only files that already exist in target folder

Tags: powershell, copy

I have a folder full of files, let's call it folder A, some of which (but not all) are also present in another folder, called folder B.

The files in B are out of date, and I would like to copy the newer versions of those files from A to B (overwrite the ones in B), but not copy all of the extra files from A which do not already exist in B.

There may also be files in B that are not in A.

Is there a way to do this with powershell? I know I can probably do it with `xcopy`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371918/powershell-equivalent-to-copy-the-xcopy-only-updated-files-that-exist-in-target) but I am looking for a pure Powershell solution.

I do not care if the files are newer, older or unchanged etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward by looping through the files in A and checking if they're in B.

```
$aDir = "C:\Temp\powershell\a"
$bDir = "C:\Temp\powershell\b"

$aFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$aDir"
ForEach ($file in $aFiles) {
    if(Test-Path $bDir\$file) {
        Write-Output "$file exists in $bDir. Copying."
        Copy-Item $aDir\$file $bDir
    } else {
        Write-Output "$file does not exist in $bDir."
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it better be `if (Test-Path (Join-Path $bDir $file.Name))` and what about copy if newer?